# How can I insert a zero in front of a number less than 10? HTML Input Box

Tags: javascript, html

I created an html input box where I would like a person to be able to enter at most 2 characters numbers (therefore from 01 to 99) and if the number is less than 10 the box must add zero by itself.

There are 2 problems:

1. If I type `00`, the script writes `000`; if I write `01` the script writes `001`, etc.
2. The box accepts numbers over 99

**Code:**

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="amount_centesimi" min="0" max="99" value="00" onchange="if(parseInt(this.value,10)<10)this.value='0'+this.value;" required>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```html
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="amount_centesimi" min="0" max="99" value="00" onchange="this.value=(parseInt(this.value)<10)?('0'+parseInt(this.value)):parseInt(this.value)" style="width: 100px" required>
```

There was two problem in your code:

```js
if (parseInt(this.value,10) < 10) this.value= '0' + this.value;
```

## 1 You missed to sanitize the value when you assign it to `this.value`.

You write code that `this.value = '0' + this.value;`

So, if your input value was `'01'`, js use the raw string value and make it `'001'` (`'0' + '01'`)

You had to sanitize the value like this:

```js
this.value = '0' + parseInt(this.value)
```

## 2 You had to change the value even if the input number was greater than 10

Or, if you input value like '000999', it will not changes to '999'

Answer (score 0):

I would use [padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart):

```
<input 
   type="number"
   class="form-control"
   name="amount_centesimi"
   min="0"
   max="99"
   value="00"
   onchange="this.value = this.value.padStart(2, '0')"
   required />
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I use PadStart it accepts values with more than two digits, for example `001`,` 002`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm doing it right, but when I used `onChange` it didn't update the value instantly, so I've used `onInput`.

Since I couldn't think of a way to track the previous value it will roll over if you keep typing numbers.

- Type 0 - get 00
- Type 1 - get 01
- Type 1 - get 11
- Type 2 - get 12
- Type 3 - get 23

```html
<input min="0" max="99" value="00" type="number" oninput="(function(e) { let value = e.value.replace(/\D/g,''); if (parseInt(value, 10) < 10) { value = '0' + value; } e.value = value.substr(-2); })(this);" />
```